# setting maxConcurrentOperationCount to one will create a serial queue?

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I have a requirement to upload array data one by one in BG thread, So I am using operationQueue for the backgroud upload, where I am subclassing the nsoperation and implemented post,
I have to upload the packets one by one serially, but not cuncurrently, 
So I am doing the following

```
private var uploadQueue = OperationQueue()
self.uploadQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
self.uploadQueue.addOperation(newOperation)
```

Will this become a serial queue? as I have set maxConcurrentOperationCount to one? if not how do I create one?

Comment: Yes that does act like a serial queue.

Comment: one word answer YES but if u need a serial queue you need not create a concurrent/operation queue and set maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1 rather you have specialized serialized queue class for that you can create one using `let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "abcd")`

Comment: Remember only serial queue that your app gets from iOS by default is main queue and all other custom serial queue u need you have to create them on your own where as you get 4 global dispatch queues by default for each app from iOS and they vary only in their priorities they are default, background, low and high

Comment: @SandeepBhandari You are confusing GCD with `OperationQueue`.

Comment: @sulthan : No am not :) I just told OP that he need not use OperationQueue and set maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1 to get the behavior of serialized queue rather he could directly create a serialized queue using GCD api, operationQueue can do much more than GCDs and quite frankly if all that u wanna achieve is serialized execution why even opt for OperationQueues when u can easily achieve the same with GCD. Lemme know if am still wrong Ill correct myself :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari For example, with GCD you cannot cancel an operation you have already enqueued. That are other differences though because both APIs are made for different purposes. GCD was created for thread communication and synchronization, especially for multiple CPU cores.

Comment: @sulthan : I completely understand. GCD is a low level api where you can not pause/suspend tasks. Once submitted they are bound to occur and you cant even add dependency among tasks in same queue which you can achieve with Operations. Thats what I meant when I said Operation queue can do lot more than GCD but because OP did not mention any of his needs like dependency management pausing/suspending tasks I though all he needs is a serialized execution of tasks may be it was mistake on my end to presume something like that but am glad I did because I got to learn something new

Comment: can you post the code for So I am using operationQueue for the background upload.